# Reorder Flatlist without re-render react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i have this code which display data on Flatlist in react native.
what i want to do is if i changed the states of one item i want it to change it's position in Flatlist without re-render the whole flatlist like animation moves the updated item to the top without having flatlist re-rendered

```
<FlatList
                data={this.state.conversations}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <ConversationView
                    currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
                    currentUserName={this.state.currentUserName}
                    conversations={item}
                  />
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.toString()}
                key={({ item }) => item}
              />
```

the component **ConversationView** has a listener when new message comes in how do i make this conversations moves to the top of the flatlist

Comment: Have you tried to put this props in flatlist : `extraData={this.state}`?

Comment: @KishanBharda not really no, let me try that

Comment: @KishanBharda By passing `extraData={selected}` to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state changes.  i don't want it to re-render i want it to stay as is just change positions of items inside.